# NSubstitute: To be able to set the reference object in the mocked method that has no return type

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, nsubstitute

I have an interface with the following declaration:

```
void MapServiceMessages(IEnumerable<ServiceMessage> serviceMessages, List<Message> responseMessages);
```

I want to mock this method that I send a servicemessage list that returns the message type list. Since it is of void type then how can I mock this method.

I don't want to change my declaration neither definition.

Of course I have choice to change void to List and then use (...).Returns(mychoiceofmessages)....

I want to check with the community if they have come across with such question and better solution.

Thanks,

Comment: @GrantWinney it is not returned because it is of reference type so whatever the value set at responseMessages object remain there.

Comment: @codebased is there a reason you don't want to change the signature?  It seems you understand that it's the only way to mock it effectively.  When you take advantage of parameter mutation as a "return value" you're creating a headache for yourself in terms of readability.

Comment: @mckeejm no specific reason except that I want to check base with the community so that I can expend my knowledge :)

Comment: @codebased looking at the docs http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/callbacks/ it seems like it expects the When..Do syntax.  Specifically the callbacks for void calls section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs on [NSubstitute callbacks](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/callbacks/)

> Returns() can be used to get callbacks for members that return a
>   value, but for void members we need a different technique, because we
>   can’t call a method on a void return. For these cases we can use the
>   When..Do syntax

```
public interface IFoo {
    void SayHello(string to);
}
[Test]
public void SayHello() {
    var counter = 0;
    var foo = Substitute.For<IFoo>();
    foo.When(x => x.SayHello("World"))
        .Do(x => counter++);

    foo.SayHello("World");
    foo.SayHello("World");
    Assert.AreEqual(2, counter);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me the direction! SO faults that it had made me to ignore what I was reading just after  http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/setting-out-and-ref-arguments/ and thanks for the direction. Well done! I could achieve without changing interface design that has been written before